# Windows command line: I find it VERY HARD to pass back-slash trailing paths as program parameter; is there a best practice?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I'm encountering such a problem. Using Visual Studio 2010, I'd like to add my postb.exe as post-build event action, like this:

```
postb.exe "$(SolutionDir)" "$(TargetDir)"
```

[image]

My postb.exe is written in C, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<3) {
        int i;
        printf("Need 2 params, only %d given.\n", argc-1);
        for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
            printf("  argv[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Your .sln dir is: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Your .exe dir is: %s\n", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

When the post-build event is fired, I do not get what I'm expecting, like this:

[image]

I think the most fatal reason is: **Microsoft Visual Studio team decided to terminate `$(Solution)` and `$(TargetDir)` with a back-slash.** Then the nightmare comes: back-slash inside a CMD shell string acts as an escape character, so the closing quote does not act as closing quote.

I think I have to use quotes(double quotes), because `$(Solution)` and `$(TargetDir)` may contain spaces.

I realize I can apply some workaround, e.g., change the post-build event .bat to be:

```
set var1=$(SolutionDir)
set var2=$(TargetDir)
set var1=%var1:\=/%
set var2=%var2:\=/%

postb.exe "%var1%" "%var2%"
```

The output becomes usable:

```
Your .sln dir is: G:/w/test/big job/
Your .exe dir is: G:/w/test/big job/Debug/
```

But that's a frustrating detour. Is there any best practice for such problem?

Comment: Hmm, no, what you show in the Output window cannot possibly be generated by that postbuild event.  It used $(TargetPath) instead of $(TargetDir).  And fumbled the double quote somehow, a backslash is not an escape char for cmd.exe, ^ is.  Update your question to show the real content of your Output window.

Comment: My screen shots are all faithful from the screen. Then what do you mean by "show real content of your Output windows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the trailing slash you can use a property function, which is already much nicer than the batchfile solution:

```
"$(SolutionDir.Trim('\'))"
```

(though as commented: I don't think this is your *real* problem here)

Comment: Very good tip. I'm realizing MSBuild's power with Visual Studio .